# Embeddings and images of number fields in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, fields, galois-groups

Let $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be a number field, and suppose that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q} ] = m$. Then there are precisely $m$ different embeddings of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ into $\mathbb{C}$, essentially by sending $\alpha$ to each of its $m$ conjugates.

On the other hand, some of the images of these embeddings can coincide, for instance if $\alpha = i$ (in which case the other conjugate is $-i$, and $\mathbb{Q}(i) = \mathbb{Q}(-i)$).

**QUESTION**: is there a criterion (for instance in terms of the Galois group of the extension) which tells us precisely how many different images we obtain ?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be something like $[K:\mathbb Q]/\#\mathrm{Aut}(K/\mathbb Q)$?

Comment: Indeed. And for $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, the size of $\mathrm{Aut}(K/\mathbb Q)$ equals the number of conjugates of $\alpha$ inside $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$.

Comment: Or in terms of the Galois group, the centralizer of the Galois group in the symmetric group.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek My comment was supposed to go on the end of your comment. "The size of $\operatorname{Aut}(K/\mathbb Q)$ equals $\dots$ or, in terms of the Galois group, $\dots$"

Comment: @WillSawin Oh I see, all right.